# memory and time efficient way to sort random incoming data

Tags: java, list, sorting, binary

I need to sort data coming from different lists of random values (values can be repeated) into a list of unique values in a memory and time efficient way (there are hundreds of lists that can have up to thousands of records each). Right now I have 2 methods

Method 1- Sort as data comes in:

```
public List<ClassB> ListSorter1(List<ClassA> listA){
    List<ClassB> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ClassA a : listA) {
        int idx = Collections.binarySearch(data, a.getValue());
        if (idx < 0) {
            int ip = -(idx + 1);
            data.add(ip, a.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2 - get all the unique data and then sort:

```
public List<ClassB> ListSorter2 (List<ClassA> listA){
    List<ClassB> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ClassA a : listA) {
        if (!data.contains(a.getValue())) {
            data.add(a.getValue());
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(data);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that method 2 performs better (about 20% faster than method 1 and roughly the same memory usage) when `<ClassB>` is simple data (Integer), but as soon as I change to a more complex class, the time required to sort the list skyrockets, taking up to 10 times more than method 1 (and still about the same memory usage), both using the same comparator function.

Why this difference in performance?
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you could just maintain a java.util.TreeSet

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "a more complex class" here... but you might want to log how many comparator calls are made in each case.

Comment: Add the values to a SortedSet, this will be more efficient and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is strange that Method 1 is 20% slower than Method 2, but I assume that it is tested on a very small collection.

Cause for a big slowdown in Method 2 is for two reasons:

1. When you iterating `data` is not sorted, so
2. `contains` method has to go through whole list in order to find element - which is **O(n)**. `contains` has O(n) complexity no meter if  data is sorted, since it iterates over the whole collection.
   So, for Method 2 it is **O(n^2)** complexity

For method 1, you are managing ordered list, and you are using `binarySearch` which is **O(ln(n))**. 
So, method 1 has a complexity of **O(n*ln(n))**

Comment: Thanks, I will continue investigating on possible improvements to the code

Comment: will do as soon as i get enough rep to do that